# on page load change to anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm using Jquery.Localscroll to move the window smoothly between anchors. How would you change the URL when the page loads to include an anchor link so it scrolls smoothly to a section when the page loads.

Or is there a better way to scroll to a section when the document loads.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously if you specify the anchor to scroll to in the tradional way:

```
<a href="yourURL#someanchor">Link</a>
```

Then the browser will scroll automatically.

If your intention is for the browser to load the page and then have your code kick in to do a smooth (animated) scroll to a particular anchor then something like this would work:

```
// on calling page
<a href="yourURL?scrollto=someanchor">Link</a>

// on "yourURL" page:
$(document).ready(function() {
   // check for "scrollto" parameter and if it exists
   // use Localscroll to move to specified anchor
   var match = /[?&]scrollto(?:=([^&]*))?/.exec(window.location.search);
   if( match != null ){
      var anchor = match[1];
      // your code to scroll to anchor here
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not quite sure what to put in `// your code to scroll to anchor here` It seems Local.Scroll finds the anchor and automatically calls the function. I'll try and put the function in there. Thanks @nnnnnnn

Comment: You're welcome. I tried to give code to determine what to scroll to based on the query string, and suggest where the scroll code should go, but I'm not familiar with Localscroll so I had to leave that part to you. Actually, thinking about it now, you might want to do it on the load event rather than the DOM ready event, so that it doesn't scroll until after images are loaded. I'm assuming that the idea is that from the user's point of view when they click a link the new page loads initially at its top and then automatically scrolls down to the appropriate anchor with some kind of animation.