# On load scroll to div localscroll not working

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor

Hi I'm having trouble implenting an answer to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556300/on-page-load-change-to-anchor)

```
// on calling page
<a href="yourURL?scrollto=someanchor">Link</a>

// on "yourURL" page:
$(document).ready(function() {
   // check for "scrollto" parameter and if it exists
   // use Localscroll to move to specified anchor
   var match = /[?&]scrollto(?:=([^&]*))?/.exec(window.location.search);
   if( match != null ){
      var anchor = match[1];
      // your code to scroll to anchor here
   }
});
```

I wasn't sure what the 'code to scroll to anchor' was in regards to .localscroll I have tried this and it doesn't seem to work.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   // check for "scrollto" parameter and if it exists
   // use Localscroll to move to specified anchor
   var match = /[?&]scrollto(?:=([^&]*))?/.exec(window.location.search);
   if( match != null ){
      var anchor = match[1];
      $.localScroll({
        target: '#section3a', // could be a selector or a jQuery object too.
        duration:1000,
        hash:true,
        onBefore:function( e, anchor, $target ){
            // The 'this' is the settings object, can be modified
        },
        onAfter:function( anchor, settings ){
            // The 'this' contains the scrolled element (#content)
        }
    });
   }
});
```

If someone has used localscroll before could they please help me fire a function when the document loads so it scrolls to an #anchor

I have tried the scrollTo feature:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.scrollTo( '#section3a' , 1000) ;

    });
```

Which works but it needs to be offset by the left -295 and the top-120

Ideally when the page loads I want to to scroll smoothly to another section. The introduction is in the middle of the long page.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the offset. I feel very silly, sorry.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.scrollTo( '#section3a' , 1000, {offset: {top:-120, left:-295} }  );
});
```